# Marketing Solutions API permissions not getting approved #linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm attempting to build a LinkedIn based application using the Marketing Solutions API which will help users use LinkedIn more efficiently.

For that we require these extra permissions:

1. r_fullprofile
2. r_member_social
3. w_compliance
4. r_compliance
5. r_primarycontact
6. r_1st_connections

I'd like to know if there's anything that we need to do in order to be able to get those permissions granted.

My team and I have spent a lot of time and resources in the last few months researching and building the use case to provide value to LinkedIn professionals. It's really unfortunate that we're not able to proceed further. We're in a very difficult position.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question for LinkedIn support, not StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

submit your question to linkedin support 
https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api-v1-migration r_fullprofile was not accessible to Marketing Developer Program developers.